# Recommendations for developing webview content on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-webview

I've got a webview component that loads some html and javascript.  The html + javascript is fairly large, and is compiled using webpack into a single page (html, javascript and css is all in one document).  I'm having trouble figuring out a reasonably efficient approach to developing my web content, and could use some advice.

My webview is loaded like so:

```
      <WebView
        ref={inputRef}
        source={
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? require('../../assets/dist/index.html')
            : { uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' }
        }

        style={{ height: 300 }}
        javaScriptEnabled
      />
```

This works on both platforms, the content is loaded and displayed as expected.  The trouble comes with developing and making changes to that content.

On IOS, it's ideal -- any changes I make to `index.html` are automatically detected, and cause the webview to reload with the new content.

However, on Android, the only way I can see changes to 'index.html' is completely rebuild and redeploy the app, which makes things really difficult.  I'm sure this is due to the `require` vs `uri` approaches necessary for the two platforms, but I'm not sure how to automatically deploy updates to `android_assets`, or if that's even possible without rebuilding?

I could also pass the `index.html` content as a raw string (i.e. using `source={{ html: myHtml }}`) but would this impact performance if `myHtml` is really large?

Is there a good way to configure Android webviews to see content changes without a complete rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended solving this (somewhat) by running a local http server on my development machine and pointing the android web view to that:

```
  const sourceUri = isEmulator
    ? 'http://10.0.2.2:9000/dist/index.html'
    : 'file:///android_asset/dist/index.html';

    return (
      <WebView
        source={
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? require('../../assets/dist/index.html') : { uri: sourceUri }
        }
        ...
      />
```

It doesn't refresh automatically on change, but at least I can reload the webview without a full rebuild.